# Reload image after it has loaded (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, refresh

I would like to reload an image which is constantly updated on the server. So far I have only tried:

---

```
setInterval(function(){
        if ($("#stream").data("loaded")) {
            $("#stream").attr("src", "http://keshira.com:8080/?action=snapshot&" + new Date().getTime());
        }
},100);
```

---

```
<img id="stream" onload="$(this).data('loaded', 'loaded');" src="http://keshira.com:8080/?action=snapshot"/>
```

---

Unfortunately this also keeps refreshing the image every 100ms. My problem is that I would like to load new images as fast a possible. So using a larger time interval is no option. Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: So does this code work? Do you want to update images more often or what?

Comment: The code updates the image constantly. It should only update the image if the last image has fully loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `load` event a bit different:

```
$("#stream").on('load', function() {
    $("#stream").attr("src", "http://keshira.com:8080/?action=snapshot&" + new Date().getTime());
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e2zfzar2/). I use `setTimeout` there only to limit it somehow, but you can remove it.

Comment: thanks simply didn't have enough knowledge of jquery.